# Auto-print the fields of a Meteor collection using helpers without specifying their name

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

Is it possible to auto-print the fields of a Meteor collection using helpers without specifying them?

Let's say I start having a helper that returns the collection of objects stored in a table, as follows:

```
{{ #each CollectionData }}
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Code</th>
       <th>Description</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <Tr class="object-row">
       <Td> {{code}} </ td>
       <Td> {{description}} </ td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>

   ...
{{/each}}
```

Now i specify an "object schema" for each collection to set which field i want to auto-print, pseudo example:

```
// Items is the name of the possible collection
Schema.items var = {
  fields {
    code: {
      columnName: "code",
      show: false,
    },
    description: {
  columnName: "description",
      show: false,
    },
    otherField {
      columnName: "foo",
      show: false,
    }
  }

}
```

Now, I would make the helper to auto-generate the table columns and values ​​of a collection field where the show check is true, without having to manually specify {{code}}, {{description}} and so on, pseudo example:

```
{{ #each CollectionData }}
   <thead>
     <tr>
      {{print each column where show check is == true, without manually specifing any name}}
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <Tr class="object-row">
       {{print the value of the column, for this record, where show check is == true, without specifing its name}}
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   ...
{{/each}}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way would be to create a template for each TD, something like

```
   <thead>
     <tr>
      {{#each fetchColumnHeaders}}
        {{> columnHeader }}
      {{/each}}
     </tr>
   </thead>
{{ #each CollectionData }}
   <tbody>
     <Tr class="object-row">
      {{#each fetchColumnItems}}
       {{> columnItem}}
      {{/each}}
     </tr>
   </tbody>
{{/each}}

<template name="columnHeader">
  <th>{{label}}</th>
</template>

<template name="columnItem">
  <td>{{label}}</td>
</template>
```

And then you can write template helpers to return the column headers, and the various items based on your schema